# How do I remove the decimal place when I set ylims in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I display my plot, the top to count numbers above the points are hidden.

[image]

I have already tried to adjust the position of the numbers with vjust and hjust, but then it just hides the bottom data point numbers.

[image]

I also tried to set the ylimits to ylim(c(0, 10)) but then the numbers on the y-axis are displayed with a decimal which I don't want.

[image]

I want them displayed as below with no decimal place, and the limit going up to 10 or 12.

[image]

Comment: Instead of `ylim`, use `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,12), breaks=seq(0,12,2))`. Setting the breaks to whole numbers will probably result round in numbers. If not, load the `scales` package, then do: `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,12), breaks=seq(0,12,2), labels=label_number(accuracy=1))`.

Answer (score 1):

A very contrived example.... does this help?

```
library("ggplot2")
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = mpg), vjust = -1.0) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2.5, 4.1), labels = scales::label_number(accuracy = 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(15, 25))
```